# Rails association and scope mindbend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers, class_name: "Follow"
  has_many :following, class_name: "Follow", foreign_key: "follower_id"

  has_many :posts
end

class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "follower_id"
end
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
current_user.followers
```

And get back a User object, not a Follow object. I did something similar for users like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_favorites, class_name: "Favorite"
  has_many :favorites, class_name: "Post", through: :post_favorites, source: :post
end
```

Then I added a belongs_to relationship for the Favorite to both :user and :post. That works fine. However, in what I'm trying to accomplish with followers, it doesn't have a bi-directional relationship (that's the best way I can describe it, I guess) so I can't get it to work using the same method.

Is there a smarter way of pulling that off? I'm talking about a Twitter-like "follow/follower" scheme where a user can follow someone and have others follow them.

My Follow model simply has a user_id and a follower_id field. I suppose it works if I do something like:

```
current_user.followers.each {|follower| follower.user}
```

But I'd like to ultimately be able to do something like:

```
current_user.followers.posts
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a join table in the middle and join to your own user table through it.

```
class User
  has_many :follows
  has_many :followers, :through => :follows, :class_name => "User"

end

class Follow
  belongs_to :user
end

create_table :follows do |f|
  f.references :user
  f.integer :follower_id
end
```

Something like that?